# Is there anything like Chronic available in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, parsing

I am looking for a very robust datetime parser, similar to Ruby's Chronic, but for PHP. strtotime() isn't cutting it for a lot of the edge cases I'm seeing in my project.

Anyone know of any good libraries?

Ideally:
- PHP 5 OOP
- well documented
- fast and stable

Thanks!

Comment: strtotime is far and away the most popular... what edge cases are you encountering?

Comment: NO answers here, but I'd be curious on the edge cases.  strToTime has always worked like magic for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the actual edge cases you are missing?  It is impossible to determine what will work with edge cases if you do not know what they are.  Are these dates that people are putting in or dates that a machine is coming up with?

Comment: humans provide them - I ended up not using strtotime() and instead using a date/time dropdown. Some edge cases were "tonight at 5pm", "next monday afternoon", etc.